# I'm in trouble with Gradle sync failed error. When project wants to reopen after restart of android studio, it rises raise an error like this::

Tags: android, gradle, directory

Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-bin\c0gwcg53nkjbqw7r0h0umtfvt\gradle-7.4-bin.zip.lck

I saw some answers to the other almost same problems, but none of them help.
Also, I deleted cashes in .gradle directory according above path, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In studio project folder :

1. delete .idea folder
2. temporary delete gradlew file
   store  it in recycle bin for safe

Close Ide, then open the project ( it might not work )

Close again, then restore the gradle file

try this